# How can I programmatically open the default browser and pass a URL in C/Linux?

Tags: c, linux, glib

Is there a convenient library call that allows me to open the default browser that I can use from C? I poked around in glib and didn't see anything. There is xdg-open, and I can just system that I guess. Any better ideas?

Comment: I think `xdg-open` is the right approach, since you can just pass it directly a URL and it will pick the user's preferred browser.

Comment: I ended up doing that because it was really simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is installed then `xdg-open` would work.

```
xdg-open http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you tagged this question with "glib", the right solution is probably to use [g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAppInfo.html#g-app-info-launch-default-for-uri) (or one of the other GAppInfo methods, depending on your exact use case).